# converting datetime to another datetime format

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I have a text file containing many date entries of the following format:

YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS.SSS AM\PM
How would you convert that to the following format?

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS (24 hour format)
This file contain many date entries, so it should change the date format of all the entries...

Thanks

Comment: Could you import the file into Excel, format the date as needed, then export as text?

Comment: You should edit your question to contain some sample lines with dates. It is possible with batch but maybe easier with a RegEx in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ksvLh3

The above script processes the DATETIME_INPUT string and processes it into the output window with the change that you requested.

To use the script:

1. open the link above.
2. paste your source datetime input over the existing data in the DATETIME_INPUT constant.
3. the page should automatically generate output in the lower window.  if not, click the Run button
4. copy/paste the results from the lower window into the destination file.

Note: I am not sure how this script will perform with large input sets.  Please specify additional requirements if needed (input size, how often you will need to run this process, does it need to be automated or one time, etc.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Provided the date time in the source file is at a fixed position like in this sample at the begin:

```
> type datetime.txt
2016/12/12 05:16:41.898 PM Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed d
2017/01/16 11:05:05.897 AM a aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et 
2017/01/25 02:07:07.457 PM no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem 
2017/05/17 05:49:08.140 PM m nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliq
2017/06/10 04:40:56.529 AM sto duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
```

A batch file can parse the elements to for variables and check for AM/PM, and in case of PM add 12 to the hour and put together with the changed delimiters (removing AM/PM)

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "usebackq Tokens=1-8* Delims=/:. " %%A in (
  "datetime.txt"
) do If /i "%%H" equ "AM" (
  Echo %%A-%%B-%%C %%D:%%E:%%F.%%G %%I
) Else If /i "%%H" equ "PM" (
  Set /A Hr=1%%D + 12
  Echo %%A-%%B-%%C !Hr:~-2!:%%E:%%F.%%G %%I
)  Else Echo no AM/PM found
```

Sample output:

```
> SU_1229322.cmd
2016-12-12 17:16:41.898 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed d
2017-01-16 11:05:05.897 a aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
2017-01-25 14:07:07.457 no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
2017-05-17 17:49:08.140 m nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliq
2017-06-10 04:40:56.529 sto duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
```